# How make windows 10 to use all 24G RAM instead of 20G?

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard

I have installed 24G into TR4 mother board. All modules were installed according to motherboard manual. (E.g. into corresponding channels). Windows boots, everything works but it see only 20G instaed of 24G even when CPU-Z which run underwindows see all 24G installed:

[image]

Memory configurations (number is nuber of DDR4 slot):

1. 8Gb
2. 8Gb
3. 4Gb
4. 4Gb
5. -
6. -
7. -
8. -

**UPDATED**

1. `msconfig -> boot -> advanced options` there is no limits, but I can not set more than 20G any way
2. Graphic card - dedicated there is no need to use system memory (in theory)
3. Note that 20G it is what windows 10 see. **Not** like  `24Gb (20Gb usable)`

Comment: I've read that sometimes ram is "stolen" for video use...

Comment: Looks like your system is 64 digits. Go to msconfig -> boot -> advanced options, is there a value specified in maximum memory?

Comment: open task manager > Performance > Open resource monitor to see how the memory is used

Comment: question updated

Comment: You should switch the slots around so you have 12GB on each channel.

Comment: What Windows version are you running?  If 7 Home Premium, there is an OS-imposed maximum RAM limit of 16GB -- do you happen to also have a 4GB video card?  This might "get-around" this limitation.

Comment: @thepip3r the OP already said it's Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should switch the slots around so you have 12GB on each channel.

This solve the problem. Thanks to [David Schwartz](https://superuser.com/users/94136/david-schwartz)